# What does "large grant" mean in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, terminology, academia

Rob Tibshirani, a statistician at Stanford university, created this amusing [comparison](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/stat315a/glossary.pdf) between machine learning and statistics:

[image]

What does "large grant" here mean?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funding_of_science#Process

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Grants fund research. The joke is that statistics and machine learning receive dramatically different amounts of funding, so what counts as a "large" amount of funding (a "large grant") is different between the two fields.